# Can I modify std::priority_queue to increment a count on duplicate data?

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, tree, priority-queue

The following code creates a priority queue, which stores Entry types.

```
struct Entry{

    //constructor
    Entry(std::string const& word_)
    : word(word_)
    , count(0)
    {}

    //let's say I overloaded the comparison operators as well.

    //data
    std::string word;
    unsigned int count;
};

std::priority_queue<Entry> entries;
```

Is it possible to modify the following priority_queue so that it detects a duplicate word and increments the count variable, instead of adding that duplicate entry?

Comment: Why not using a `std::map` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `std::priority_queue` requires *strict weak ordering*, your data is basically incompatible with it. Modifying it should not be possible. The only thing you can do is to re-implement it yourself. Starting with `std::set` as base type should be a good idea since it already keeps elements sorted.